# mean and variance for max of n random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_k)$ be a set of n independent random variables  with the same distribution function $F_X(x)$ and let $Y=max(X_k)$  The distribution function for $Y$ is $F_Y(x)=F_X^n(x)$.  The first two moments (to get mean and variance) of $Y$ are $\mu_i=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^iF_Y'(x)dx$ (asssuming density function exists).

If the $(X_k)$ have a uniform distribution, the moments are easy to calculate.  However I would like to see if there has been a calculation of these moments for a normal distribution or other interesting distributions.

Comment: You will find a proof for the normal case here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381212/distribution-of-maximum-of-normally-distributed-random-variables

Comment: Why does $F_Y(x)=F_k^n(x)$ two parameters?

Comment: @ zoli Error in statement. Corrected.

Comment: @Caventa The expressions for the moments in terms of the distribution functions are easy to set up (as in the reference).  The question I am asking - have any of them been explicitly evaluated?